# Angular Repeat table rows with radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, radio-button

I have an angular app that that generates a table of radio buttons with `ng-repeat`. I want to be able to click on the table row or the radio button itself to select it and store the value somewhere. The problem is it only works if I select the radio button and not when I click the row. Additionally, I want to have it where only 1 radio button can be selected at any given time. Here's my html:

```
<tr class="info" ng-repeat="id in ctrl.ids"
    ng-click="id.isChecked=!id.isChecked;
    ctrl.toggleSelectedRow($event, id)">
    <td>
        <input  type="radio"
                ng-model="id.isChecked"
                ng-click="ctrl.toggleSelectedRow($event, id)"/>
        <a>{{id}}</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Here's my angular code:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var selectedRow;

MyCtrl.prototype.toggleSelectedRow = function($event, selectedId) {
    var _this = this;
    $event.stopPropagation();
    selectedRow = selectedId;
};

MyCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$log', '$http', '$sce'];
app.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);
```

When I run this code all the radio buttons are selected even though I'm using `stopPropagation()`. Clicking on the table row rather than the radio button saves the information but it doesn't select the radio button for the user to see. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit 1:**
Here's a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/QMfC4ar8WrGRHbBk6gyR?p=preview) that reproduces my problem. I've gotten mostly everything to work except selecting the radio button when you click on the table row rather than the radio button directly.

Comment: Can you show more of your code? I guess you have a general misunderstanding... `MyCtrl.prototype`  setting a method on your controller prototype is not the angular way of doing things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To toggle your radio-button by clicking the table-row as well, you can simply add a click-handler on the tablerow `<tr>` .
I edited your plunker with the following code:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in main.items" ng-click="main.selectedItem=item">
```

An updated version of your plunker can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/gjPG9aOGReB9KILZnPPq?p=preview).

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the name attribute to your radio buttons. Then you don't have the problem, that more than one element is selected

```
<input  type="radio"
                name="myRadioButton"
                ng-model="id.isChecked"/>
```

What do you want to do in function toggleSelectedRow()?

If you have finished your choice, you can just loop through array `ids` and get the checked item. Then you don't have to call some function.

Comment: I tried this but this ended up with all the radio buttons being selected at startup. Can you provide a plunker or something to show what you mean?

Comment: I made a [plunker here](https://plnkr.co/edit/QMfC4ar8WrGRHbBk6gyR?p=preview) to reproduce my problem